# How to force browser to clean up dom element never added to DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

In a React application, I am creating a custom component, this component generates `<video>` elements used by three.js's [`VideoTexture`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/textures/VideoTexture)s.

Everything works, except that after unmounting the component, even when the three.js webgl context is being destroyed, the video elements that were playing continue to keep playing.

I'm struggling even to find a way in the devtools to monitor the state of these "ghost" `<video>` elements, mainly because they are not ever even added to the DOM.

So far the best idea I have is to do something extremely silly like add these to the DOM right before unmounting the component (and subsequently they would be removed due to unmounting the component). I just wish there was a better way.

Comment: Would help to see how you do generate these video elements and how they're linked (or not) with the other parts of the code. Even a detached video with no reference to it can not be collected while it's playing a media (moreover when it has sound). You need to clear its source first (`video.src = ""; video.srcObject = null`).

Comment: Thanks, clearing the source seems like a nice idea, I didn't think of that. Well, in practice, when we add the video elements to the DOM at the end right before component unmount, this does appear to cause them to get cleaned up. So it is good enough for now.